# Aggregate ZNC logs

Tags: logging, irc

I have ZNC set up, and I'm trying to get logging to create a single aggregate log file for a channel.  I can get the channel to generate logs, however, they're broken down by day, and I can't seem to figure out how to configure the path (I keep getting:

```
Unable to load module [log] [Module [log] aborted: Invalid log path [].]
```

)

Is there a configuration file I can edit instead of going through ZNC's web interface?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and yes.

Per the [ZNC wiki](http://wiki.znc.in/Configuration) there's a few places the files can be stored depending on your install and the way the module is set up (certain versions had logging as a core module, others do not).

Configuration for the logging module supports a number of date variables for setting the way the files will be named. [The docs page for the module](http://wiki.znc.in/Log) shows examples like:

```
 global:  $USER/$NETWORK/$WINDOW/%Y-%m-%d.log
 user:    $NETWORK/$WINDOW/%Y-%m-%d.log
 network: $WINDOW/%Y-%m-%d.log
```

In any case, if you're not going through the web UI, you'd need to manually reload/restart ZNC to make the changes take effect.